# Using a Proof by contradiction to Prove a statement in Elementary number theorey

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove the following statement

For all odd integers $a$,$b$ and $c$ if $z$ is a solution to the equation $ax^{2}+bx+c=0$ then $z$ is irrational.

What i tried

Im assume the negation of the statement and try to prove by contradiction

I assume the  statement, there exists odd integers $a$,$b$ and $c$ such that $z$

is a solution to the equation $ax^{2}+bx+c=0$ and $z$ is rational.

And i have to find a contradiction in this statement

I know that since $z$ is rational, then z can be written in the form $i/k$.

And since $z$ is a solution to the equation $ax^{2}+bx+c=0$

This is equivalent to saying $az^{2}+bz+c=0$

Which is then equivalent to $a(i/k)^{2}+b(i/k)+c=0$

Could anyone explain how do i continue from here. Thanks

Comment: It is easier to show that the discriminant $b^2-4ac$ cannot be a perfect square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with the discriminant

Assume, $$b^2-4ac=k^2$$

Then the left side is odd, so $k$ is odd.

The above equation is equivalent to $$(b-k)(b+k)=4ac$$

But one of the factors $b-k$ and $b+k$ must be divisible by $4$, the other
divisble by at least $2$, so the left side is a multiple of $8$, but the right
side is not because $a$ and $b$ are odd. (Note that the case $b=\pm k$ is impossible
because of $4ac\ne 0$).

Answer (score 1):

Multiply through to show that $a i^2 + b i k + c k^2 = 0$, where $a,b,c$ are odd integers and at most one of $i,k$ is even. Therefore mod 2, $i^2 + i k + k^2 = 0$, or $i + i k + k = 0$.

- If $i, k$ are both odd, this is a contradiction immediately.
- If $i$ is even and $k$ odd (or vice versa), then we get a contradiction again.
- $i, k$ can't both be even because the rational can be represented in its lowest terms.